# Question marks instead of Unicode characters with resource bundle in view

Tags: jsf, character-encoding, localization, liferay

I use Primefaces 3.5 + Lifaray 6.2.
I need some internalization in my app.
I use `Language_en_US.properties` file and others for string resources.
In backbean I use `ResourceBundle.getBundle` and it's working propertly.

But in view I use

```
<p:outputLabel value="#{i18n['server-address']}"/>
```

And with Cyrillic i always got question marks on page

> ?????? ??????

It's in page code already as question marks, so it's not a browser problem.

If I use ResourceBundle.getBundle directly

```
<p:outputLabel value="#{adminBean.getString('main')}"/>
```

then I got Cyrillic.

Is there any way to use i18n without bean?

Comment: This suggests that the one responsible for `#{i18n}` is doing its job wrong. This is however not recognizable as a standard JSF problem (at least, I've never worked with portlets). How exactly is your `#{i18n}` configured? Via `<resource-bundle>` in `faces-config.xml`, right? Or is that done differently in portlets?

Comment: <hook>
 <language-properties>Language_en_US.properties</language-properties>
 <language-properties>Language_ru_RU.properties</language-properties>
</hook>
in liferay-hook.xml and
<application>
  <locale-config>
   <default-locale>ru</default-locale>
   <supported-locale>en</supported-locale>
  </locale-config>
 </application>
in faces-config.xml
This is all "by default" for new liferay portlets in Eclipse.

Comment: That's not recognizable as standard JSF. Problem at its whole also not. Looks Liferay specific. I'll fix the tags so right people are attracted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Liferay expects the resource bundles to be encoded in UTF-8 (unlike `PropertyResourceBundle` in plain Java, which uses ISO-8859-1).

Check encoding of you `Language_ru_RU.properties` file - most likely it is not UTF-8. That would explain that ResourceBundle.getBundle works correctly, while `#{i18n['server-address']}` doesn't.

While it's a deviation from the standard, UTF-8 encoding is quite comfortable, as there's no need for character escaping.

See [Localizing JSF Portlets](https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/6-2/localizing-jsf-portlets) in Liferay documentation.